# Convert string to CString

Tags: c++, type-conversion, stdstring, c-strings

I have a string which is declared like this:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO tblVehicle (OVImage) VALUES ('";
query += decodedData;
query += "')";
```

(where 'decodedData' is a string holding Base64 data)
when i convert it to 'CString' using this code

```
CString cQuery = query.c_str();
```

I get just this line in 'CQuery':

```
"INSERT INTO tblVehicle (OVImage) VALUES ('ÿØÿà"
```

and the rest of the string is not in the 'CQuery'. what should i do to have long text in CString?

Comment: `decodedData` is likely not really base64. It seems like it contained "ÿØÿà" with a premature NULL character, which messed up your string because it thinks that's the end of it.

Comment: @VoidStar i have 'decodedData' in a text file, and as far as i checked, there's no unusual character atleast after "ÿØÿà"

Comment: A null wouldn't show up in a text editor (it would probably appear as a space). Also, a base64 string with any normal mapping does not contain `ÿ` nor `Ø`, etc. This just looks like binary data, not base64. A typical base64 string: "SWFtNjdwb3VuZHN5b3VuZw0K"

Comment: What type is `decodedData`, how is it declared?  Is it at `std::string` or something else?  If it's something else, which definition of `operator+=` is being invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see a string suddenly "end" like that, you can infer that there is a null character (0) in the source string at that point. C strings are otherwise known as null-terminated strings because the first null character indicates the end of the data. `std::string` tolerates these, but when you stick it into the `CString`, it gets cut off at that point because the null in the data tells it to stop there.

`decodedData` does not contain valid base64 data; it appears to just be casted binary data. Casting binary data to a string ends up resulting in random null characters so that's a no-go for CString. Just looking at "ÿØÿà", it's pretty clear that it's not a normal base64 string, because base64 strings typically contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, and /. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 . Since a proper Base64 string won't contain null, this problem won't happen.

Edit: Regarding the problem with the base64 string... One easy way to remove the nulls from your string is to just replace them all. Assuming `decodedData` is a string...

```
std::replace(decodedData.begin(), decodedData.end(), '\0', '!');
```

Then you can tell where the nulls where showing up. But there is probably a reason for this that you should figure out.

Comment: as you both mentioned i had converted the Base64 to binary in the previous lines of code, but with Base64 i still have the problem and CString has only this part in it:  "INSERT INTO tblVehicle (OVImage) VALUES ('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD/7gAOQWRvYmUAZAAAAAAB/+ESCEV4aWYAAE1NACoAAAAIAAcBMgACAAAAFAAAAGIBOwACAAAABwAAAHZHRgADAAAAAQAEAABHSQADAAAAAQA/AACcnQABAAAADgAAAADqHAAHAAAHbgAAAACHaQAEAAAAAQAAAH0AAADnMjAwOTowMzoxMiAxMzo0OD"

Comment: If you're storing it as a text file, you might be accidentally putting a null in with your editor somehow, or might be reading EOF into the string or something. Maybe you should just filter that stuff when you read the file in. Also, try printing `CString::GetLength()` to make sure you're displaying the entire string.

Comment: I just store it as text for my tests, i don't read it from the text file

Comment: There still has to be something wrong with `decodedData`, but I'd need to see more code to figure out what.